# solana candy machine - is it possible to know if user click approve in transaction

Tags: javascript, wallet, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I am using the solana candy-machine for minting the nft.

When i call smart contract function in javascript

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";

let program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId, provider);
let result = await program.rpc.someFunc(); //here is the smart contract function
```

browser will show pop up for you to approve the transaction.
is There any way to know if user click cancel or approve?

In ethereum, it has something like below:

```
          .on("transactionHash", function(hash) {
                …
          })
          .on("error", function(error, receipt) {
        …
          });
```

is it possible to do it in candy machine? I want to do something after user click approved in transaction

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve something similar, however this would not be effective from the candy-machine directly.

There are probably multiple ways of doing it, but one that I found is using [`connection.getSignatureStatuses()`](https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/web3.Connection.html#getSignatureStatuses) from Serum.

Code would look something like this, and it is similar to what you shared:

```js
// Impor the connection dependencies
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';

// Loop using waiting for a positive status / or timeout
while (...) {

  // Get the status using the transaction ID
  const statusResponse = await connection.getSignatureStatuses([
    txId,
  ]);

  const status = statusResponse?.value[0];

  if (status.err) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Once you get the status of the transaction, which includes the user rejecting it, you can trigger the behavior in the frontend.